# Is "Window.showModalDialog();" deprecated in new version of firefox (**51.0.1**) ? . This is recent release

Tags: firefox, modal-dialog, firefox-developer-tools, showmodaldialog

I'm experencing following issues while using modal dialogue from Javascript

Comment: Looks like you posted your question too early. It is missing the issues you're talking about.

Comment: You appear to have not bothered to even do the most [basic search for `Window.showModalDialog()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=Window.showModalDialog()). If you had done so, the *first result* would have directed you to the [MDN page on `Window.showModalDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog) which would have told you in warning and notice banners at the top of the page that it is deprecated, has been removed from Chrome, and that it wil be removed from Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [related MDN page, `Window.showModalDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog) is a deprecated proprietary API, which is going to be removed in [bug 981796](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=981796).

You should use the [`<dialog>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) as replacement once it's implemented (see [bug 840640](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=840640)).